# Update without touching timestamps (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Is it possible to update a user without touching the timestamps?

I don't want to disable the timestamps completly..

grtz

Comment: There's no method to override timestamps by default. I'm not sure, but have you tried DB::raw($yourRawQuery)?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Disable it temporarily:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->timestamps = false;
$user->age = 72;
$user->save();
```

You can optionally re-enable them after saving.

**This is a Laravel 4 and 5 only feature** and does not apply to Laravel 3.

Comment: I've run into problems with this...? Doesn't work when set in the base model. Anyone else have an issue?

Comment: Can you explain at all any more? Still can't get this to work and seems stupid. Also using Laravel 3.

Comment: It's basically disabling `timestamp` before saving, in Laravel 3 the property is static, so I'm not sure if you can or not change it in runtime, look at the code: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/3.0/laravel/database/eloquent/model.php#L71

Comment: This is the only solution that has worked for me. I had tried to do the more "elegant" way : `$something->save(['timestamps'=>false]);` and it just ignored it. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: this still causes relationships to update if the model has "touches" defined.

Answer (score 31):

In Laravel `5.2`, you can set the public field `$timestamps` to `false` like this:

```
$user->timestamps = false;
$user->name = 'new name';
$user->save();
```

Or you can pass the options as a parameter of the `save()` function :

```
$user->name = 'new name';
$user->save(['timestamps' => false]);
```

For a deeper understanding of how it works, you can have a look at the class `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`, in the method `performUpdate(Builder $query, array $options = [])` :

```
protected function performUpdate(Builder $query, array $options = [])
    // [...]

    // First we need to create a fresh query instance and touch the creation and
    // update timestamp on the model which are maintained by us for developer
    // convenience. Then we will just continue saving the model instances.
    if ($this->timestamps && Arr::get($options, 'timestamps', true)) {
        $this->updateTimestamps();
    }

    // [...]
```

The timestamps fields are updated only if the public property `timestamps` equals `true` or `Arr::get($options, 'timestamps', true)` returns `true` (which it does by default if the `$options` array does not contain the key `timestamps`).

As soon as one of these two returns `false`, the `timestamps` fields are not updated.

Comment: Note that this functionality is broken in Laravel 5.1 and 5.2, and has therefore been *removed* from Laravel 5.3.  See: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/10028

Comment: It does not work in laravel 8

Comment: Not tested, but it seems possible in Laravel 8 to set the property of the model `$timestamps` to FALSE before calling the update() method.

Comment: Setting `$user->timestamps = false;` works for me in Laravel 8. Only the option of the save method has been removed.

Answer (score 23):

Above samples works cool, but only for single object (only one row per time).

This is easy way how to temporarily disable timestamps if you want to update whole collection.

```
class Order extends Model
{

 ....

    public function scopeWithoutTimestamps()
    {
        $this->timestamps = false;
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Now you can simply call something like this:

```
Order::withoutTimestamps()->leftJoin('customer_products','customer_products.order_id','=','orders.order_id')->update(array('orders.customer_product_id' => \DB::raw('customer_products.id')));
```

Comment: its Order:: **w** ithoutTimestamps(), please fix

Comment: In Laravel 9, I'm using `public function scopeWithoutTimestamps($query) { $this->timestamps = false; return $query; }`

Answer (score 20):

To add to Antonio Carlos Ribeiro's answer

If your code requires timestamps de-activation more than 50% of the time - maybe you should disable the auto update and manually access it.

In eloquent when you extend the eloquent model you can disable timestamp by putting

**UPDATE**

`public $timestamps = false;`

inside your model.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I had to do `public $timestamps = false;`

Comment: fixed my answer to what @JonathanEllis stated - its now a public property

Comment: Really `public`, not `protected` (visibility)?

Answer (score 19):

If you need to update **single model** queries:

```
$product->timestamps = false;
$product->save();
```

or

```
$product->save(['timestamps' => false]);
```

If you need to update **multiple model** queries use

```
DB::table('products')->...->update(...)
```

instead of

```
Product::...->update(...)
```

Comment: Everyone's calling it "model" when they mean "instance". A model is not an actual instance, it's just the class/definition that isn't an actual real object. This is a widespread falsehood, sadly.

Comment: @GeneC We could say he's not updating instances either, he's updating the database, usually rows (specially in the second example when he "updates multiple models").

Answer (score 18):

For Laravel 5.x users who are trying to perform a `Model::update()` call, to make it work you can use

```
Model::where('example', $data)
     ->update([
       'firstValue' => $newValue,
       'updatedAt' => \DB::raw('updatedAt')
     ]);
```

As the Model::update function does not take a second argument anymore.
ref: [laravel 5.0 api](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_update)

Tested and working on version 5.2.

Comment: this is really helpful in Laravel 5.8 when i do multiple records update in one go and i don't want to touch the default process of updated_at functionality.

Comment: This is very clever actually, and works on most versions on Laravel. I even tried on 4.2 and it works!

Comment: Thank you for this.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the situation of needing to do a mass update that involves a join, so `updated_at` was causing duplicate column conflicts. I fixed it with this code without needing a scope:

```
$query->where(function (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query) {
    $query->getModel()->timestamps = false;
})
```

Answer (score 6):

## Laravel 9 and above

Taken directly from the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#timestamps).

If you would like to perform model operations without the model having its `updated_at` timestamp modified, you may operate on the model within a closure given to the `withoutTimestamps` method:

```php
Model::withoutTimestamps(fn () => $post->increment(['reads']));
```

So in OP's case, the code will be something like this:

```php
User::withoutTimestamps(function () {
    $user = User::find(1);
    $user->name = 'John';
    $user->save();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

For Larvel 5.1, you can also use this syntax:

```
Model::where('Y', 'X')
    ->update(['Y' => 'Z'], ['timestamps' => false]);
```

Comment: Tested this in Laravel 5.7 and this does _not_ work.

Comment: Laravel 5.7: 
`Type: InvalidArgumentException`
`Message: Unexpected data found.`

Answer (score -1):

Laravel 8

Doing some overrides using seeders and on one test I have:

```
$item = Equipment::where('name', item_name))->first();
$item->description = 'some description';
$item->save(['timestamps' => false]);
```

Which works fine, but if I use `firstOrNew` then the `$item->save(['timestamps' => false]);` does not work.

```
// This does not work on Seeder file
$item = Model::firstOrNew(['name' => 'item_name']);
$item->description = 'some description';
$item->save(['timestamps' => false]);

// Doing the following works tho
$item = Model::firstOrNew(['name' => 'item_name']);
$item->description = 'some description';
$item->timestamps = false;
$item->save();
```

So in some cases you would use one over the other... Just check with die and dump to see whether `+timestamps: false`

```
$item->timestamps = false;
$item->save();
```

or

```
$item->save(['timestamps' => false]);
```

Edit:
In my project I opted using `$item->timestamps = false;` so I would recommend using this as well. Here is a working snippet from laravelplayground:
https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/4ae950f2-d057-4fdc-a982-34aa7c9fee15

Check the HasTimestamps on Laravel api:
https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasTimestamps.html

and the save method on Model:
https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html

The save method still accepts options but passing timestamps will not work.

Comment: Does not work...

Comment: @Gass can you tell me which one did you tried and didn't work in your case. There are cases where you should use `$item->timestamps = false;` over `$item->save(['timestamps' => false]);`. One of the method I mentioned should work.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what happened `$item->save(['timestamps' => false]);` did not work on my Laravel 8 app

Comment: @Gass for laravel 8 `$item->timestamps = false;` would work as  I mentioned on the post. I simulated a code snippet on laravel playground here: https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/63bb8098-8fe8-43bf-9e74-3d320f82c6f9