# Update Eloquent model without touching timestamp (Laravel 3)?

Tags: php, laravel, timestamp, laravel-3

I need to update an Eloquent model in Laravel 3 without touching the automatic timestamp. Code is super simple:

```
$thread->views = $thread->views + 1;
$thread-> save();
```

However that also updates the timestamp. I've seen this: [Update without touching timestamps (Laravel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904853/update-without-touching-timestamps-laravel) but it does not seem to work in L3, or maybe I've done something wrong. In the Thread model there is:

```
public static $timestamps = true;
```

Which updates the `updated_at` timestamp field in the database. I need to update the thread model somehow without touching the timestamp. Anyone know how? The documentation http://three.laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent does not have anything about this issue...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answered my own question with a workaround. Just do:

```
$thread->views = $thread->views + 1;
DB::table('threads')->where('id', '=', $thread->id)->update(array('views' => $thread->views));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works for L3, but in L4 I think you can do:

```
$thread->timestamps = false;
$thread->save();
```

Comment: This hasn't worked for me in L3... if you can get it to work somehow would love to see though.