# Laravel prevent updated_at from updating for specific query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using the standard `updated_at` and `created_at` on a table.

My results are ordered by `updated_at` since they can be edited.

However, on a page I am updating a row counter (views). This means that the `updated_at` will be updated with the new date/time but I want to prevent this.

Is there any way to do this? Or am I going to have to use `created_at` to order my results?

I would rather not use my own manual `created_at` and `updated_at`

Comment: `class ModelName extends Eloquent {
    public static $timestamps = false;
}`

Comment: That would just remove them, I want to keep them but prevent updating the `updated_at` for a specific query

Comment: Never mind, found the answer here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904853/update-without-touching-timestamps-laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904853/update-without-touching-timestamps-laravel)

Answer (score 21):

For **single model** queries:

```
$product->timestamps = false;
$product->save();
```

For **multiple model** queries use

```
DB::table('products')->...->update(...)
```

instead of

```
Product::...->update(...)
```

Comment: You can do `$product->fill($fields); $product->save(['timestamps' => false]);` and encapsulates this into a utilities class (e.g. `\App\Utils\Models\Products::saveProductNoUpdateAt(\App\Models\Product $product, array $fields)`). Then you have no `DB` (no model abstraction) but still a single place for deactivating auto-update of `updated_at`.

Comment: Remove "on update current timestamp" from DB