# Laravel Disable auto "updated_at" when Incrementing Fields

Tags: php, laravel, timestamp, laravel-5

I'm incrementing some total fields in my table

```
$model->total_comments += 1;
$model->save();
```

However this triggers the date to update for `updated_at`. I want to disable it for these cases. I know I can do it manually and disable auto update for the the timestamp fields altogether. But hoping there is a simple way to do it.

EDIT:

Adding example from my code. Note that there are no Observers set on this model.

```
namespace App\Models;

class Language extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{

}

$router->get('/test', function () {
    $model = \App\Models\Language::find(1);

    $model->words_total = $model->words_total + 1;
    $model->save(['timestamps' => false]);

    return 'boo';
});
```

Comment: So you don't want timestamps when updating?

Comment: Whenever I find myself "needing" to disable the updated time stamp; I conclude that I have an attribute in my model that does not belong there. I would not define `total_comments` as a property of the model, I would count the numbers of comments. Try to keep the database normalized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note** there is currently a bug in the framework that prevents the first solution from working. I will keep this post up to date if it get's fixed. [Github issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/10028)

---

You can pass an options array to `save()` and disable timestamps for that one save:

```
$model->save(['timestamps' => false]);
```

Of course you could also set the property on the model, but this would require you to set it back to `true` if there is the possibility that you are going to continue to work with the same model instance:

```
$model->timestamps = false;
$model->save();
$model->timestamps = true;
```

Comment: Not sure what's going on with the `->save(['timestamps' => false)`. When I do `->getDirty()` it doesn't show the `updated_at`. I can even comment out the `updateTimestamps` method in `Eloquent\Model`. Also disabled all observers. The thing still updates the `updated_at` field. I'm getting it from cache, but don't see how that should matter. It also inherits from a parent model, which then inherits from a `BaseModel`. As the `updateTimestamps` method is completely commented out (and dump-autoload run) I can't find the source of how this is still updating.

Comment: Strange. Is it possible that your database actually updates the field with a new timestamp? (in mysql with `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`) To be certain, log DB queries and see what Eloquent actually executes.

Comment: I have a debug bar and it is including the `updated_at` in the update query. I've checked the table and see no auto update there. When I do it through the second method by manually enabling/disabling `$model->timestamps` it doesn't fire. I guess it would mean it's not from the MySQL end in this case.

Comment: Hmm. From just looking at the framework code I don't see a reason why the option shouldn't work... [view on Github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1547)

Comment: Not an Eloquent expert, but maybe some bug in the Builder. if you look at `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model@performUpdate` method there is a line `$this->setKeysForSaveQuery($query)->update($dirty);` which from `setKeysForSaveQuery` receives a `Builder` object. The update is being called from that `Builder` which seems to ONLY check the models `timestamps` field and no longer the `timestamps` argument. Inside of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder@update` there is a line `return $this->query->update($this->addUpdatedAtColumn($values));` which if you follow along will set the update field.

Comment: That definitely looks like a bug to me! I'll look into it and fix it if I can. I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the timestamps temporarily by doing this before save.

```
$model->timestamps = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Disable it for temporary

```
$model->total_comments += 1;
$model->timestamps = false;
$model->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution-1:

```
$model = Table::find($planId);
$model->timestamps = false;
$model->increment('popularity');
$model->save();
```

Solution-2:

```
DB::table('Table')
->where(‘id’, $planId)
->increment(‘popularity’,1)
```

for more information
https://medium.com/@panjeh/laravel-eloquent-model-increment-with-or-without-updating-timestamps-1274c6cd7f52

Answer (score 0):

You can update a record without changing the `created_at` or `updated_at` timestamps by saving the current value of those columns e.g in `updated_at`:

```
Model::where('id', $id)->update(['column' => "value", 'updated_at' => DB::raw('updated_at')]);
```

You may also check this thread [Update without touching timestamps (Laravel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904853/update-without-touching-timestamps-laravel).