# laravel update table without changing updated_at

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am trying to figure out how to update a table in controller without updating the column updated_at

I don't want to completely stop updated_at I am using it in other places, I just want to update something and not update the updated_at in a certain place

I tried

```
$model->timestamps = false;
$model->save();
```

it still updates the updated_at column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update without touching timestamps (Laravel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904853/update-without-touching-timestamps-laravel)

Comment: @OlegNurutdinov as I said ... that does not work for me

Comment: Did you try `$model->timestamps = false;` as in question from link?

Comment: You need to do `$model->timestamps = false`. In your case, you are just defining a variable called timestamps and setting it to false.

Comment: I updated my question, that was a mistake from my side. I actually meant $model->timestamps = false;

Comment: You could try [this](https://implode.io/uLyn1O)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to check your database structure and see if this is a database level condition or a Laravel mechanism. You can check the database schema by running the following MySQL command:

`describe {table}`

If you see anything in the extra column of the results for your `updated_at` column along these lines:

```
on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Then this is a database level condition I suggest you remove it. And let Laravel take responsibility for the `updated_at` column.

Comment: That is exactly what fixed it, thank you ! I assume that is the doing of Voyager ? as in does that automatically if you add the table through the BREAD / Database ?