# Ignore the updated event when an Eloquent model is restored

Tags: laravel, events, eloquent, event-handling, laravel-9

I am building a [package](https://github.com/elaborate-code/laravel-eloquent-logs) that logs changes that happen on eloquent and I'm trying to figure out what to check to ignore the `updated` event when `restored`.

```php
trait HasLogs
{
    public static function bootHasLogs(): void
    {
        // created ...
        self::updated(callback: fn ($model) => self::log($model, 'updated'));

        self::deleted(callback: function ($model) {
            // Ignore 'deleted' event when 'softDeleted' or 'forceDeleted'
            if (in_array('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes', (class_uses(self::class)))) {
                return;
            }
            self::log($model, 'deleted');
        });

        if (in_array('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes', (class_uses(self::class)))) {
            // softDeleted ...
            self::restored(callback: fn ($model) => self::log($model, 'restored'));
            // forceDeleted ...
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Here is the actions order if that helps:

1. `Model::restore()` on the `SoftDeletes` trait.
2. ---- `restoring` is fired.
3. ---- `Model::save()`
4. -------- `saving` is fired.
5. -------- `Model::performUpdate()`
6. ------------ `updating` is fired.
7. ------------ `Builder::update()`
8. ------------ **`updated` is fired**.
9. -------- `Model::finishSave()`
10. ------------ `saved` is fired.
11. ---- `restored` is fired.

Comment: Pretty sure you can simply disable timestamps via `self::timestamps = false;` as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904853/update-without-touching-timestamps-laravel

Comment: @TimLewis that would only avoid the call of  `Model::updateTimestamps()` in `Model::performUpdate()`

Comment: Is there another spot then where `updated_at` is changed? I haven't dug into the chain of events called via `Model::restore()`, but I also haven't run into a case where I care if `updated_at` is changed via `restore` 

Comment: @TimLewis `Model::performDeleteOnModel()` from the `SoftDeletes`  doesn't touch the `timestamps` since it calls directly the `Builder::update()`. But `Model:restore()` goes through `Model::performUpdate()`.

Comment: And I found that only `performUpdate` and `performInsert` check `usesTimestamps()` then use `updateTimestamps()`

Comment: I made this PR https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/43467

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trait `HasLogs` adds a Boolean attribute to the `Model` named `loggableIsBeingRestored` set to `false` by default.

The trait also registers a new listener for `restoring` which sets `loggableIsBeingRestored` to `true` at the begging of the described actions.

Then the `updated` listener checks for `loggableIsBeingRestored` before proceeding with its actions.

```php
trait HasLogs
{
    public bool $loggableIsBeingRestored = false;

    public static function bootHasLogs(): void
    {
        // ...

        self::updated(callback: function ($model) {
            if (isset($model->loggableIsBeingRestored) && $model->loggableIsBeingRestored) {
                // This is a restored event so don't log!
                return;
            }

            self::log($model, 'updated');
        });

        // ...

        self::restored(callback: function ($model) {
            self::log($model, 'restored');

            $model->loggableIsBeingRestored = false;
        });

        self::restoring(callback: function ($model) {
            $model->loggableIsBeingRestored = true;
        });
    }
    // ...
}
```